# KeyError: ('var1', 'occurred at index 16')

Tags: python-3.x, apply

I'm getting this weird error msg: **KeyError: ('var1', 'occurred at index 16')** on th following line of code:

```
df['var1'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['var1']*row['var2']), axis = 1)
```

I'm multiplying 2 columns of the df DataFrame. And `16 in df.index` is `True`. I can access the 16th row normally. If i drop that row, the error persists.

Any thoughts on this?

**EDIT**:
As requested, a sample of the data:

```
             X        var1                          Y \
0    US4642867729  22.3052  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
1    US4642867729   5.9139  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
2    US4642867729   3.0799  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
3    US4642867729   2.9647  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
4    US4642867729   2.5798  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
5    US4642867729   2.5281  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
6    US4642867729   2.3359  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
7    US4642867729   2.2434  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)
8    US4642867729   1.8624  Korea; Republic (S. Korea)

                          W             Z     \
0    Information Technology  US4642867729
1    Information Technology  US4642867729
2                 Materials  US4642867729
3               Health Care  US4642867729
4    Information Technology  US4642867729
5                Financials  US4642867729
6    Consumer Discretionary  US4642867729
7                Financials  US4642867729
8                 Materials  US4642867729

                                                  var2
0    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
1    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
2    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
3    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
4    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
5    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
6    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
7    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
8    0.16258420849834973043179786600376246497035026...
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Sure! Look at the Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to multiply the two columns and store the result in the first one, you can solve this with an even easier solution than using `apply` and `lambda`:

```
df['var1'] *= df['var2']
```